# How to read specific files of known filenames with pandas after using os.walk?

Tags: python, pandas, operating-system

I am using os.walk() to get all the files in a certain directory; however, there are a ton of files in that directory that I don't need. I know the specific names of the files that I want to read as they update everyday and only the date of the filename changes.

```
import pandas as pd
import os
from os import listdir, walk
from os.path import isfile, join

td_str = pd.to_datetime('today').strftime('%Y%m%d') # Returns '20200923'
path = 'C:\\Users\\myuser\\subdirectory\\' + td_str
for root, directories, files in os.walk(path, topdown=False):
    for name in files:
        print(os.path.join(root, name))


### The Output
# C:\Users\myuser\subdirectory\20200923\20200923_file_a.csv
# C:\Users\myuser\subdirectory\20200923\20200923_file_b.csv 
# C:\Users\myuser\subdirectory\20200923\20200923_file_c.csv
# C:\Users\myuser\subdirectory\20200923\20200923_file_d.csv
```

I know I want to read file_b and file_c and put them into respective dataframes.

```
df_file_b = pd.read_csv('C:\Users\myuser\subdirectory\20200923\20200923_file_b.csv')
df_file_c = pd.read_csv('C:\Users\myuser\subdirectory\20200923\20200923_file_c.csv')
```

How can I read those specific files only with pandas? I currently assume I might have to do something like have the desired filenames in a list and do an `if` loop to check if os.walk() finds it, but is there a more efficient way to do this?

Thanks much.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the glob module, supporting patterns: [10.7. glob — Unix style pathname pattern expansion](https://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html).

A simple solution would be to create a filter with `file_` and the character range `b` to `c`:

```
import glob
print(glob.glob('*file_[b-c]*'))
```

This will print

> ['20200923_file_b.csv', '20200923_file_c.csv']